# CSS file wont link with HTML

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvnPx.jpg   --Webpage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtmH5.jpg  --CSS file

cant seem to link css file I have tried ALOT and it just wont work. i feel like its a directory issue somehow but i never had such a issue like this before. I have troubleshot quite a bit. and its getting pretty frustrating considering i should be studying, but I'm stuck here with this issue i know i need to fix and understand.

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable.

Comment: in your `index.html`, is there `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`? so your HTML can read your css! if you want to put image at least put the html file image

Comment: i wish i could edit this post to fix the image problems lol yes i added another image that didn't show up on the post. https://imgur.com/a/YPmLV8P

Comment: @david try to not use ❌`rel="stylesheet.css"` but ✅`rel="stylesheet"`, then tell me if is working

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas sounds good. I did that. still wont read it.  i have played around with everything it feels like. and it just wont budge.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xxgn22u here is how everything looks

Comment: there is typo there :)

Comment: David on the last photo that you attached in the comments, it is blurry, but it seems to me that you have written in the path to the file stylsheet.css, but file stylesheet.css

Comment: ❌ `href="stylsheet.css"` to ✅`href="./stylesheet.css"`

Comment: if the problem of before is fixed, so write **another question** on StackOverflow with the code of the new error, what you tried, what the error say

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
 i have done that already. still not working.

Comment: its fixed! it was sloppy directory issues i cleaned it up and it worked fine. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `<link rel="stylesheet.css" href="stylesheet.css">` but correct

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: yes, it's obvious , but anything happens, we will tell OP and everything will work out for him

Comment: its not the problem unfortunately, its something definitely something that should have been fixed. but not the full problem. https://imgur.com/a/xxgn22u i'm not sure if posting pictures down here is ok or not but if not forgive me.

Comment: Typo there, write stylesheet.css